# Django list view repeatedly fails, but detail pages work

Tags: python, django

testt1
is my view for taking a queryset and turning out a list of objects and their foreign key children.

mydetail
is the detail view for the individual objects. No slug is used in the list, but it is in the list template to call the detail pages. But all these errors come from trying to call the **list**, not the detail. *If I just type the slug into the address bar, all my detail pages come up just fine!*

I have tried a lot of different things, and get a **lot** of different errors, but the bottom line is always the same: no list

1. **named url fails**

   Error during template rendering
   In template /home/malikarumi/Projects/hattie/templates/base.html, error at line 44
   Reverse for 'jhp_url' not found. 'jhp_url' is not a valid view function or pattern
   name.

‘jhp_url’ is the named url for the **detail** page.

But here is line 44:

```
<link href="{% static 'plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

the urlpattern:

```
path('<slug:slug>/', mydetail, name='jhp_url'),
```

the call to reverse():

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse(‘jhp_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

2. **namespaced url fails**

Error during template rendering
In template /home/malikarumi/Projects/hattie/templates/base.html, error at line 44
Reverse for 'jhp_url' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[^/]+)/courts/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Now it has an empty string for the slug. The pattern is right. If it had a slug, it would work.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('bench:jhp_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

list template:

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'bench:jhp_url' slug=C.slug %}">{{ C.name }}</a></h3>
```

urlpattern is the same.

3. **no slug passed**

   testt1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'slug'

Which means that as I have currently defined it:

```
def testt1(request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
print(request.slug)
```

Is not being provided the slug variable / value. Now it might also be a question of position, so I changed only this:

```
def testt1(request, *args, **kwargs):
```

But since slug is still in the return value, now I get:
Unresolved reference 'slug'

I take it out, and the autoreloader wakes up…

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'slug'

Yes, well, that's what I suspected. That’s why I had the print in there. The question is: *why* does it not have slug?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs
Whenever Django encounters include(), it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the included URLconf for further processing.

Apparently, I don’t understand this process, because I always assumed this meant the slug part of my url was being passed along as part of the request object. But now I see that the word 'slug' does not appear in the docs on the response request page:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/

4. **extra arguments fail**

The docs also give the option of passing ‘extra arguments’:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-include
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions

But this says **nothing** about using extra arguments in conjunction with named or even namespaced urls. Does that mean they don't, or can't go together? Then shouldn’t they say so explicitly, like the Zen of Python? Anyway, my efforts in this area all failed miserably:

```
File "/home/malikarumi/Projects/hattie/bench/urls.py", line 13
path('<slug:slug>', mydetail, name='jhp_url', {'slug': slug}),
                                              ^
```

SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Are they saying a dictionary is a **positional** argument, and **not** a keyword?

```
File "/home/malikarumi/Projects/hattie/bench/urls.py", line 14, in <module>
path('', testt1, slug='slug', name='testt1'),
TypeError: _path() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'

File "/home/malikarumi/Projects/hattie/bench/urls.py", line 13, in <module>
path('<slug:slug>', mydetail, slug='slug', name='jhp_url'),
TypeError: _path() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'

File "/home/malikarumi/Projects/hattie/bench/urls.py", line 13, in <module>
path('<slug:slug>', mydetail, name='jhp_url', slug=slug),
NameError: name 'slug' is not defined
```

It's not? then wtf is 'slug:slug'???

Clearly, the slug is not being passed. If it isn't happening automatically,
and it isn't part of the request object - despite slug:slug in the
urlpattern, and I can't use these extra arguments, how am I supposed to get
the slug passed?!

5. **explicit slug keyword argument in view fails:**

```
File "/home/malikarumi/Projects/hattie/bench/views.py", line 22
        def testt1(request, *args, '<slug:slug>', **kwargs):
                                   ^
        SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Just in case you wondering, yes, I did try explicitly passing the slug as a keyword. All such efforts failed.

```
def testt1(request, slug=slug, **kwargs):
```

unresolved reference slug

```
def testt1(request, slug=self.slug, **kwargs):
```

unresolved reference self

**UPDATE**
As requested, here is my latest version of views and urls, and at the bottom a link to the full stacktrace going back to yesterday.

VIEWS

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from bench.models import Jurisdiction
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from statedict import sdl
j = Jurisdiction.objects.all()
from urllib.parse import urlparse


def mydetail(request, slug, **kwargs):
    court = j.get(slug=slug)
    # twodigit = twodigit
    return render(request, 'bench/jhp_.html',
                  {'court': court})


def testt1(request, **kwargs):
    federalcourts = j.filter(sphere="Appeals").filter(purview="Federal")
    circuits = federalcourts.order_by('siblingrank')
    scotus = circuits.first().name
    context = {'circuits': circuits, 'scotus': scotus, 'slug': slug}
    return render(request, 'bench/listtest1.html', context)
```

URLS

```
from django.urls import path
from bench.views import  mydetail, testt1

app_name = 'bench'

urlpatterns = [

    path('/', mydetail, name='jhp_url'),
    path('', testt1, name='testt1'),
]
```

STACKTRACE:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ktm-y_AEUrllw0kSctlLgUyNfxVx6eFnYlOZCs-jM2w/edit?usp=sharing

thank you

Comment: Please include a full snapshot of your urls, views and the full stacktrace. The various attempts you made are helpful, but some of them added more problems. It'll be easier to suggest changes if we are working from a common base.

Comment: @schillingt here it is

Answer (score 1):

I would drop the **kwargs from your views unless you have a good reason not to. The reason is that it will hide problems with your views and urls.

The way I would write your views and urls are as follows:

```
# views.py

def mydetail(request, slug):
    ...


def testt1(request):
    ...


# urls.py

app_name = 'bench'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/', mydetail, name='jhp_url'),
    path('/', testt1, name='testt1'),
]
```

The fully qualified url names for these would be:

- `bench:jhp_url`
- `bench:testt1`

If you're using something like:

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'bench:jhp_url' slug=C.slug %}">{{ C.name }}</a></h3>
```

And it's still giving you an error about `Reverse for 'jhp_url' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found.`, then the issue is that `C.slug` is resolving to an empty string or None, or `C` is None.