# re_path syntax in *application* urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I have been getting this error for almost a week. I have googled and checked the docs and looked for youtube videos. I cannot find an answer to this seemingly simple and obvious question: What is the syntax for re_path() in the included urls from my apps?

error:

```
Reverse for 'jhp_url' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s)  
tried: ['(?P<twodigit>[a-z]{2,3})/courts/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

That pattern *is* correct! So obviously, the problem is slug has an empty string. But why? I have it in reverse():

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('jhp_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

**Q1:Why isn't it seeing the kwarg from reverse() and using self.slug?**

If I try to put self.slug in the view or the url as extra arguments, PyCharm complains.

Putting the namespace in reverse() and the template makes *absolutely no difference!* I get the same error.

BUT, if I take the namespace *out* of those two(1) places, I get a *different error*:

```
Reverse for 'jhp_url' not found. 'jhp_url' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

(1) as opposed to having it in one but not the other

So it seems like the first error I mentioned here is closer to being right.
My debug_toolbar template context says:

```
 'slug': '^(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$'
```

I'm pretty sure that's wrong. It should be the actual slug and not the pattern. That's why I have focused on the app urls.py. But, as I said at the top of this rant. I have not been able to find *anything* on the syntax of re_path() in the included app urls!

bench.urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"^$", twodigit_testt1, {'slug': r"^(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$"}, 
            name='tdr'),
re_path(r"(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$", courtdetail, name='jhp_url'),
```

Of course I still get these errors, but my point here is that the interpreter *runs* with that. But when I try things like

```
    re_path(r"^$", twodigit_testt1, {'slug': r'^(?P=slug)/$'}, name='tdr'),
```

I just get syntax errors.

Finally, please note that these errors are coming because the list template that twodigit_test1 is calling has urls to the individual detail pages in it. If I take the detail urls out of the template, it works. But if I go directly to the detail page, after importing my app views into the project urls, that works, too! It's only the *list template + detail urls* combination that is the problem - and if you can't list your details on your list page, what's the point? I have tried both the url template tag and get_absolute_url in the template. Finally, I did ask an earlier version of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68912530/django-list-view-repeatedly-fails-but-detail-pages-work/68915720#68915720). I know some people don't like that but it did not resolve this issue. I have reworked and refocused the question so it is not identical. Plus, I wasn't using re_path() then.

Comment: `self.slug` seems to be blank and that will cause the url to not match. Can you confirm that the model instance has slug?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. Someone suggested this to me a few days ago. When I checked, indeed there were some instances that didn't have slugs. So I fixed that, thinking my problems were solved. They weren't. Now I have come to see autoescape as the problem, or rather, the fact that {% autoescape off %} has no effect.